# How to store mongoDB's nested documents in pandas without duplication

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I am reading a data from mongoDB and storing it in pandas dataframe for further exploratory analysis and machine learning
My mongoDB document looks like this..

```
{ 
   "user_id"    : "user_9",
   "order_id"   : "order_9",
   "meals"      :  5,
   "order_area" : "London",

   "dish" : [
      {
         "dish_id"          : "012" ,
         "dish_name"        : "ABC",
         "dish_type"        : "Non-Veg",                
         "dish_price"       : 135,
         "dish_quantity"    : 2,
         "ratings"          : 4,
         "reviews"          : "blah blah blah",
         "coupon_type"      : "Rs 20 off"
      },
      {
        "dish_id"          : "013" ,
        "dish_name"        : "XYZ",
        "dish_type"        : "Non-Veg",                
        "dish_price"       : 125,
        "dish_quantity"    : 3,
        "ratings"          : 4,
        "reviews"          : "blah blah blah",
        "coupon_type"      : "Rs 20 off"
      },
   ],
}
```

Once I get the data in python I use json_normalize to split dish related attributes while inserting it into a dataframe

```
 df=  json_normalize(db.dataset2.find(), 'dish',           
 ['_id','user_id','order_id','order_time','meals','order_area']
```

which gives me following in pandas

```
  coupon_type     dish_id  dish_name  dish_price  dish_quantity
0     Rs 20 off     012      ABC      135            2
1     Rs 20 off     013      XYZ      125            3

  ratings    reviews      coupon_type  user_id order_id  meals order_area
0   4     blah blah blah  Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
1   4     blah blah blah  Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
```

Problem with this is data is duplicated in (user_id,order_id,meals,_id & order_area)
Whats the other approach to store this data in a data frame without duplication?

Comment: I had not heard of the `pandas` library before, so this question title was very interesting to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for a `MultiIndex`, which at least gives the appearance of avoiding `duplication` - [(see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)):

```
df = json_normalize(data, 'dish', ['user_id', 'order_id', 'meals', 'order_area'])
df = df.set_index(['user_id','order_id', 'meals', 'order_area'])

                                  coupon_type dish_id dish_name  dish_price  \
user_id order_id meals order_area                                             
user_9  order_9  5     London       Rs 20 off     012       ABC         135   
                                    Rs 20 off     013       XYZ         125   

                                   dish_quantity dish_type  ratings  \
user_id order_id meals order_area                                     
user_9  order_9  5     London                  2   Non-Veg        4   
                                               3   Non-Veg        4   

                                          reviews  
user_id order_id meals order_area                  
user_9  order_9  5     London      blah blah blah  
                                   blah blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks alot..yes this is what I wanted.. But,will I be able to fit machine learning model on `MultiIndex` data?